# Where does gdb get installed to when using WSL in VS Code?

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, c, visual-studio-code

I'm using Visual Studio Code to write C and I'm using the WSL terminal. I installed `gdb` from the VS Code terminal to debug my code, but I have to change `miDebuggerPath` to `gdb` installation path. But I can't find where `gdb` got installed into? What would my path be?

Comment: [This bug report](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/2811) might be relevant for your question.

Comment: Try `C:/dev/GDB/gdb.exe`.

Comment: What is gdp? Did you mean something else?

Comment: He’s referring to `gdb`, the GNU Debugger. He only misspelled it every time except once. // It most certainly won’t be at `C:\dev` when he used WSL to install it.

Comment: Where did you install gdb? In WSL?

Answer (score 0):

it should be in /usr/bin/gdb.

In your WSL directory for example:

"C:\Users\jamie\AppData\Local\Packages\CanonicalGroupLimited.Ubuntu18.04onWindows_79rhkp1fndgsc\LocalState\rootfs\usr\bin\gdb"